# Issues scaling ul li with background img

Tags: html, css, html-lists

So, I'm currently messing around with building a web page and I'm having issues getting an list to scale with the background image when resizing the web page. For example, I have text in the center of the page that is also in the middle of the background image but when I resize the page the text moves up the screen while the background image gets bigger. How does one get the text to scale with the background image..? Is this possible? Should the <ul <li and the background image be under one <div? I know im missing something here..

```css
#wrapper {
    margin-left: auto;
    margin-right: auto;
    width: 960px;
}

#imagescale {
  width: 100%;
  height: 100%;
}

#imagescale {
  background-repeat: no-repeat;
  background-position: center top;
  text-align: center;
}

#imagescale:before {
  content: "";
  display: inline-block;
  height: 100%;
  vertical-align: middle;
  margin-right: -0.35rem;
}

.stretch {
  width: 100%;
  height: 100%;
}

html {
  background: url(https://www.pexels.com/photo/laptop-on-desk-near-lush-houseplant-5797997/) no-repeat center center fixed;
  -webkit-background-size: cover;
  -moz-background-size: cover;
  -o-background-size: cover;
  background-size: cover;
}

html,
body {
  height: 100%;
}

.container {
  bottom: -20px;
  right: -15px;
  min-height: auto;
  max-height: 100px;
  position: relative;
  display: block;
  align-items: center;
  justify-content: center;
  margin: auto;
  font-size: 3vmin;
  word-wrap: break-word;
  font-family: 'Franklin Gothic Medium', 'Arial Narrow', Arial, sans-serif;
}

.container .center {
  display: block;
  padding: 40px;
  position: absolute;
  top: 50%;
  left: 50%;
  -o-transform: translate(-50%, -50%);
  -ms-transform: translate(-50%, -50%);
  -moz-transform: translate(-50%, -50%);
  -webkit-transform: translate(-50%, -50%);
  transform: translate(-50%, -50%);
  text-align: center;
}

.background {
  width: 100%;
  height: 600px;
}

img {
  max-width: 100%;
  max-height: auto;
}

ul {
  list-style-type: none;
  background-size: contain;
}
```

```html
<div id="wrapper">
  <div class="background">
  </div>
</div>
<div class="nav-bar">
  <div id="imagescale" class="stretch">
  </div>
  <div class="container" id="nav-menu">
    <div class="center">
      <ul>
        <li> <a href="/">text</a></li>
        <li> <a href="/">text</a></li>
        <li> <a href="/">text</a></li>
      </ul>
    </div>
  </div>

</div>
```

[Example Image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/kycSv.jpg)

Comment: I'm a bit lost as to how your CSS ties up with your HTML. What background are we talking about?

Comment: html {
  background: url(https://www.pexels.com/photo/laptop-on-desk-near-lush-houseplant-5797997/) no-repeat center center fixed;
  -webkit-background-size: cover;
  -moz-background-size: cover;
  -o-background-size: cover;
  background-size: cover;
}

Comment: I'm trying to get text to center in the middle of the laptop display in the image and stay there when resizing the browser. I feel like containing the image in the same <div as the <li would make more sense but that doesn't seem to work either.

Comment: Is the text you are talking about the whole ul? If not could you describe what is to stay centrally on the screen in the image?

Comment: I attached a screen shot of what I have for an example. The text is centered where I want it relative to the background image. When I scale the page, the background image gets larger(as it should), but my text stays the same, which in turn makes the text not be in the center of the laptop display. Sorry if Im making this harder than it needs to be for you to understand, Im new at all of this lol.

Comment: Obviously it wont have an issue with a screen shot because it's a captured state. I just wanted to give you a visual of what I'm working with. Image gets bigger but text stays the same when live previewing the code. I need the text to enlarge or shrink depending on the size of my browser along with the background image so that the text always remains inside the display of the laptop.

Answer (score 0):

see if this is what you are looking for

```css
* {
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
}

.image-scale {
  background: url(https://images.pexels.com/photos/5797997/pexels-photo-5797997.jpeg?auto=compress&cs=tinysrgb&h=750&w=1260);
  background-repeat: no-repeat;
  background-position: center center;
  background-attachment: fixed;
  object-fit: cover;
  width: 100%;
  height: 100vh;
  display: flex;
  flex-direction: row;
  justify-content: center;
  align-items: center;
}

.menu {
  background-color: teal;
}

.menu ul {
  font-family: 'Franklin Gothic Medium', 'Arial Narrow', Arial, sans-serif;
  color: violet;
  list-style-type: none;
  background-size: contain;
}
```

```html
<div class="image-scale">
  <div class="menu">
    <ul>
      <li> <a href="/">text</a></li>
      <li> <a href="/">text</a></li>
      <li> <a href="/">text</a></li>
    </ul>
  </div>
</div>
```

EDIT NEW:

```css
.image-scale {
    width: 100%;
    height: 100vh;
    display: flex;
    flex-direction: row;
    justify-content: center;
    align-items: center;
}

.image-scale2 {
    position: relative;
}

.image-scale2 img {
    max-width: 100%;
    width: 100vw;
    height: 100vh;
}

.menu {
    position: absolute;
    background-color: teal;
}

.menu ul {
    font-family: 'Franklin Gothic Medium', 'Arial Narrow', Arial, sans-serif;
    color: violet;
    list-style-type: none;
    background-size: contain;
}
```

```html
<div class="image-scale">
    <div class="image-scale2">
        <img src="https://images.pexels.com/photos/5797997/pexels-photo-5797997.jpeg?auto=compress&cs=tinysrgb&h=750&w=1260" alt="">
    </div>
    <div class="menu">
        <ul>
            <li> <a href="/">text</a></li>
            <li> <a href="/">text</a></li>
            <li> <a href="/">text</a></li>
        </ul>
    </div>
</div>
```

Comment: hmm. not quite. or at least not on my browser. looks like your text is above the image and not in the center of it (center being relative to the laptop display on the image). You did give me an idea though so I'm testing it now. We'll see what happens! Thanks for the input!

Comment: I added a new edit. could you please check?